# How to get column data combining old.variablename in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, audit, database-trigger

I'm trying to build an audit trigger function (that works for more than one table) that retrieves the column of the table's primary key. For example, there's a table customers that has 'customerid' as primary key, and there's a table orders that has 'orderid' as primary key.

With this, i find the name of the column/primary key of the table that triggered the function and store it in 'prim'.

```
prim :=(SELECT c.column_name
    FROM information_schema.key_column_usage AS c
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints AS t
    ON t.constraint_name = c.constraint_name
    WHERE(t.table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME) AND t.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY 
KEY');
```

That actually works. Prim would be literally 'orderid' or 'customerid', depending on which table triggered the function. Now, what i want to do is get the info of the column i retrieved, and insert it in the audit table. So let's say I deleted a row from the customers table, i want to insert that event in the audit table. I try to do:

```
INSERT INTO audit(columnname,dataincolumn,tablename)
VALUES(prim,old.prim,tg_table_name);
```

I know there's a lot wrong with it, but how can I get my output to be:

```
COLUMN     DATAINCOLUMN    TABLE
--------------------------------
customersid    12     Customers
orderid        23     Orders
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  record "old" has no field "prim"
```

Comment: Why don't you use of the already available trigger implementations? [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)  or [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) or [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky, but you can do it using dynamic SQL and casting the value to the correct type.

Assuming that you have a `bigint` variable `val` (or `integer`, depending on your needs), you can do:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT (($1)::%I).%I', TG_TABLE_NAME, prim)
INTO val
USING OLD;
```